# DynamoDB enum input validation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Suppose, you want to create a rest api method for different car brands (BMW, AUDI, MERCEDES).
You also want to create a new car, including the car brand as property.

How can I validate if the car brand exist, before creating a new car in the table?

From the front-end, you want a dropdown list (select / option).
From the backend you want to validate the input.

What is the best practice for this?
The get car brands method will read the dynamodb table too often, creating hot partitions.

Comment: how is front end interacting with backend? if this is inserted into Dynamo via Lambda function, we will need to add that validation in Lambda itself. or if you are using api gateway, we can setup request validation at api gateway.

Comment: POST /car/brand to post a new car (admin only). GET /car/brand to show a dropdown for the frontend, so you can search/filter on it (users). But when a user wants to create a car, validate that the car brand exists (backend lambda) before storing it.

Answer (score 0):

The API call to the DynamoDB table when attempting to create a new car brand would be to use a [Conditional Put](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.PreventingOverwrites). That way you would say "only insert this new car brand if it does not exist already".

For the read of list of car brands, if this is something in your UI that is presented thousands of times per second, then i'd have an out of band lambda function that updates the list only when a new car brand is input (use DynamoDB Streams). I would put that list X number of items all with the same data, but different PKs. For example: pk = "CarBrandList_0" all the way through pk = "CarBrandList_5". In your code to get the car brand list, you give it the PK and a random number between 0 and 5. You have now avoided creating hot keys

Comment: Thanks for your solution! So for every new car brand, i have to update 5 (or more) rows, which will immediately update the lambda function with the new data it return. And for backend validation, for example creating a new car with a brand as property that exists. I can just call the dynamoDB get with a random ID at the end as PK?

Comment: That's the idea. I would update the 5 items in a transaction, with some kind of error that gets bubbles it to something that is monitored if the transaction fails. just to be sure. The likelyhood that failing is low, but you get the idea.